# How to have one-button access (on HTC incredible) to do voice dialing or voice commands?

Tags: cyanogenmod, htc-droid-incredible, voice-command

My wife finds her HTC Incredible incredibly difficult to make a quick call without having to look at the screen.  She'd like to have a one-button activation of the voice dialing or voice commands "call <   >" or ""

I thought one option might be to reprogram the optical trackball button.

This is rooted with CyanogenMod.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about the optical mouse specifically, but CyanogenMod does give you the option to alter the behavior of the various capacitive/hard buttons on the phone to some extent. In `Settings->CyanogenMod Settings->Input` you can set the long-press behavior of the home and menu buttons, and completely change the behavior of the search button.

What I've typically done is set the search key (or long-pressing the search key) to open up the voice search app. You could substitute the voice dialer or anything else you wanted if you set it up this way, with the trade-off being that you lose the default search functionality (in my case it's okay because I never use the search button).

Answer (score 1):

One solution i found is:  if you long-press the search button this brings up the voice command (for me it gave an option of Messaging or vLingo)